# Return filtered hierarchy in SQL - CTE/SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

We have a requirement to return the hierarchy of "active" account records into a specific format via SQL.

Here's a link of my sample data and expected results: [SAMPLEDATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53m1Q.png)

Considerations:

- Parent Account will be blank if the parent of the account is 'inactive'
- Root Parent will be the topmost 'active' parent
- Inactive accounts will be removed from the table

I already got the whole hierarchy of the accounts (Recursive CTE). However, the problems are the Parent Account and the 'Root' columns. I can't seem to get the correct values for them if the hierarchy is complex or has inactive parents. (e.g. If the topmost parent is inactive or if there multiple parent accounts and some are inactive)

I've tried to use subqueries for those columns but I think I'm still missing something...

Can anyone enlighten me with the right approach to this? Thanks in advance!

Here's my script:

```
WITH aCTE ([Client Number], [Client Level], accountid) AS
(
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parentaccountid ASC) [Client Number]
  ,0 [Client Level]
  ,accountid
FROM
  Account
WHERE
  parentaccountid IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
  b.[Client Number]
  ,b.[Client Level] + 1
  ,a.accountid
FROM
  Account a
  JOIN aCTE b ON a.parentaccountid = b.accountid
WHERE
  a.statecode = 0 --Active
)

SELECT DISTINCT
  ac.[Client Number]
  ,ac.[Client Level]
  ,fa.accountnumber [Account Number]
  ,fa.[name] [Account Name]
  ,[Parent Account] = CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 a.[name] FROM Account a JOIN aCTE b ON a.accountid = b.accountid 
        WHERE b.[Client Number] = ac.[Client Number]
        ORDER BY b.[Client Level] ASC) != fa.[name]
    THEN fa.parentaccountidname
    ELSE ''
  END 
  ,[Root Parent Number] = (SELECT TOP 1 a.accountnumber FROM Account a JOIN aCTE b ON a.accountid = b.accountid 
  WHERE b.[Client Number] = ac.[Client Number]
  ORDER BY b.[Client Level] ASC) 
  ,[Root Parent Name] = (SELECT TOP 1 a.[name] FROM Account a JOIN aCTE b ON a.accountid = b.accountid 
  WHERE b.[Client Number] = ac.[Client Number]
  ORDER BY b.[Client Level] ASC) 
FROM
  FilteredAccount fa
  JOIN aCTE ac ON fa.accountid = ac.accountid
WHERE 
  fa.statecode = 0 --Active
ORDER BY
  ac.[Client Number] ASC
  ,ac.[Client Level] ASC
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and the query that you have.

Comment: It seems you have a pretty good idea of what to do, but are just missing a detail. It's difficult for us to abstractly understand your issue, so we can't easily help you. Please post the query result you have, and the one you expect.

Comment: Hello! I've clarified my question above. I hope this is more understandable now. TIA.